# How i fix this PSPICE orCAD problem? - Model D1N747 used by D_D1 is undefined

Tags: orcad

- From [PSPICE NETLIST] section of C:\SPB_DATA\cdssetup\OrCAD_PSpice\17.0.0\PSpice.ini file:
  .lib "nomd.lib"

*Analysis directives: 
.TRAN  0 500ms 0 
.OPTIONS ADVCONV
.PROBE64 V(alias(*)) I(alias(*)) W(alias(*)) D(alias(*)) NOISE(alias(*)) 
.INC "..\SCHEMATIC1.net"

**** INCLUDING SCHEMATIC1.net ****
* source ELECTRICAI_LAB_2_PUNTO_1
D_D1         0 N00392 D1N747 
D_D2         N00346 N00392 D1N747 
R_R1         N00148 N00346  1k TC=0,0 
V_V1         N00148 0  AC 0
+SIN 0 10 60 0 0 0

**** RESUMING ElectronicaI_Lab_2_Punto_1.cir ****
.END

ERROR(ORPSIM-15113): Model D1N747 used by D_D1 is undefined

ERROR(ORPSIM-15113): Model D1N747 used by D_D2 is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the root part number is 1N747, not D1N747. It is a 3.6 volt 500 mW zener in a glass case. I searched several sites and it is embedded in a long list of part numbers starting with 1N746. OrCAD may not have a dedicated path to that part number.

Also since I have UltraLibrarian it was not part of the ULO inventory. It may require a trace to a manufacture who offers Pspice data. I have version 17.2.0 64 bit and I cannot find it either. You may need to find a similar part that has Pspice data.

Comment: I usually use the 1N914 and actually use with it. I have  the version 17.2.0 too. Thanks for you answer! .

Comment: If my answer was of any help please check the up-vote or accepted box's to the top left of the answer.